# Java Recursion - Converting Tree to String

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a TreeToHtmlConverter that has a public static function called convert. The function recurses through the tree to build up the HTML String and returns it.

Example Code:

```
public class TreeToHtmlConverter {
  public static String convert(TreeNode root) {
    if (root.isLeaf()) {
      return "leaf";
    }

    String childHtml = root.getChildren().stream()
        .map(child -> convert(child))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    return "<p>" + childHtml + "</p>";
  }
}
```

I need to add behavior to the function such that it returns the HTML String as well as a list of special elements contained within the HTML (keeping it generic because what's in the list isn't important). Additionally, there could be future behavior added in which I need other info gathered while building the HTML. One of the main goals is to not add another traversal of the HTML to gather this information and get everything in one pass.

Idea

```
public class TreeToHtmlConverter {
  public static TreeToHtmlResult convert(TreeNode node) {
    List<String> specialTags = new ArrayList<>();
    String html = convert(node, specialTags);

    return new TreeToHtmlResult(html, specialTags);
  }

  public static String convert(TreeNode node, List<String> specialTags) {
    if (node.isLeaf()) {
      return "leaf";
    }

    if (node.isSpecial()) {
      specialTags.add(node.getName());
    }

    String childHtml = node.getChildren().stream()
        .map(child -> convert(child, specialTags))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());

    return "<p>" + childHtml + "</p>";
  }

  private static class TreeToHtmlResult {
    private final String html;
    private final List<String> specialTags;

    public TreeToHtmlResult(String html, List<String> specialTags) {
      this.html = html;
      this.specialTags = specialTags;
    }

    public String getHtml() {
      return this.html;
    }

    public List<String> getSpecialTags() {
      return this.specialTags;
    }
  }
}
```

Any thoughts are appreciated, let me know if I can provide any more info to help guide the conversation.

Comment: Please, check this [ask], and show us your code, what do you have so far.

Comment: @SergeiSirik Updated the description to have some example code to help discuss over :)